# Hybris Database Connection

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

For some reason we need to run database native query instead of flexible query. For running those queries we need DB connection so how can we get the jdbcTemplate or DataSource object from Hybris.

Comment: For what exactly? You can also use DB relative conditions on flexible search. If the code is not recognized as flexible search it will be pass as is in the DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of a script groovy that can achieve this :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities;
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry;

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

try
{
    conn = Registry.getCurrentTenant().getDataSource().getConnection();

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("your sql query here...");

    pstmt.execute();

}
catch (final SQLException e)
{
    LOG.error("Error!!");
}
finally
{
    Utilities.tryToCloseJDBC(conn, pstmt, null);
}

return "Groovy Rocks!"
```

---

Edit : find more details in this article https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/run-native-sql-query-hybris/